# how do I add a click attribute to a DIV without it applying to elements inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I have a DIV that when clicked on expands to reveal some inputs and buttons, and will close when clicked on again, hiding those elements. The problem I am having is that when I click on the buttons or the input boxes the closing animation happens anyway. I know I can solve this by taking the inputs and buttons out of the DIV but the DIV is very important for their formatting and organization. Any help would be great, thanks!

html:

```
<div id='inputArea1' class='inputAreas'>
   <input id='email' class='evInput' placeholder='example@gmail.com'>
   <input id='comf' class='evInput' placeholder='Comfirmation Code'>
   <button id='sndCde' class='evBut'>Send Code</button>
   <button id='comfBut' class='evBut'>Comfirm</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var main = function() {
  $('.box').click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (!el.hasClass('selected')) {
      el.animate({
        "height": "300px"
      }, 200)
      el.addClass("selected");
      el.find('.inputAreas').show();
    } else {
      el.animate({
        "height": "85px"
      }, 200);
      el.find('.inputAreas').hide();
      el.removeClass("selected");
    }
  })
}
$(document).ready(main);
```

FULL CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2vzga0/

Comment: `.click()` sends the internal click event object to your function. you can use that to see what the EXACT target of the click was: `.on('click', function(e) { if (e.target == .....) { ... } });`

Comment: @MarcB I thought of that, but in this case (see Fiddle), the title inside also needs to be clickable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.stopPropagation();` can do the job:

```
$('#inputArea1').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Fixed Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbogfdka/)

Comment: Wow didn't think it would be nearly that simple! I'm going to have to do more research on .stopPropagation now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Joshua Glad it helped you. [This doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5:_Event_Propagation) explains how event propagation (or bubbling) works. If you click on an element, the event is propagated to its ancestors (wrapping elements). This function prevents that. I should also mention that I used it on one element here, using its ID `#inputArea1`. But if you want to apply it to all of your tabs, you should give all of your tab contents a common class, such as `.inputAreas`, and use that instead. Then you only need to write this once.